# Same system, same code, different behaviors: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, windows-services, windows

There are many questions about "***The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.***" error message and it seems very few of them were answered. I couldn't find any answer about my case, also my problem is little bit different.

I have a Windows Service. It sends data to web service with SSL at a certain time of day. Normally Windows Service doesn't work like Windows Application, so I change Main() method like;

```
WinService service = new WinService();
service.ServiceStart();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

It works successfully and sends data.

I rollback changes in Main() method and it looks like

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
{ 
    new WinService() 
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

When I install Windows Service and start it, I get error like "***The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.***".

**Same system, same code, it works successfully as Windows Application but doesn't work as Windows Service.** What does problem look like?

Comment: I would look at permission issues depending on which user your service and your application run as.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, your comment enlightened me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Windows Service's permission settings in **Properties** window's **Log On** tab, changed account from ***Local System*** to ***My User Account*** (Logged In User) and it works like a charm.